# How to generate Fixed Minute based DateTime using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I need help generating `Minute` based `time-range` for a pre-defined `Date`.

The `Date` range values will change so I should be able to update it.

I also want to exclude `Friday` and `Saturday` from the generated data.

**What did I do?**

I successfully generated the `date-range` by doing this:

```
pd.date_range(start='1/1/2017', end='8/06/2019', freq='T')
```

But how do I add `Minute` data and exclude `Friday` and `Saturday`?

Once this is done, I want to create a column name called `'TIME_MIN'` and assign it to a `df`

Could you please help?

Comment: Why do you need to add `Minute` data? It's already there and easily available through the accessor: `DatetimeIndex.minute`. Or if it needs to count from 0 - 24hrs do `idx-idx.normalize()` where `idx` is your above `DatetimeIndex`

Comment: It looks like I have a minute data too. Now it needs to be `index` and assigned to a `df`. Also, the last Minute value should end at `23:59:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude Friday and Saturday using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': pd.date_range(start='1/1/2017', end='8/06/2019', freq='T')
})
df.loc[~df['time'].dt.weekday_name.isin(['Friday', 'Saturday'])]
```

Output:

```
    time
0   2017-01-01 00:00:00
1   2017-01-01 00:01:00
2   2017-01-01 00:02:00
3   2017-01-01 00:03:00
4   2017-01-01 00:04:00
5   2017-01-01 00:05:00
6   2017-01-01 00:06:00
7   2017-01-01 00:07:00
```

...

Comment: Thank you for composing the answer. Why does it have 2 columns? and how do I create a column `TIME_MIN` in a `df`

Comment: It is just a series with index. It is not a dataframe.

Comment: In this case, I think it needs to be `index` and assigned to a `df`. Also, the last `Minute` value should end with `23:59:00`

Comment: Why? Where in your question you have stated these things? :(((

Comment: Updated the answer to have a dataframe

Comment: Thank you, just one last request, the last value is `2019-08-06 00:00:00`. It is supposed to be `2019-08-05 23:59:00`

Comment: you need to replace `dt.weekday_name` by `dt.weekday` otherwise it threw out error probably due to new updates of pandas package.